# sbt stuck loading project

Tags: scala, sbt

when I run the following command:

```
 sbt -mem 2048 update
```

sbt stuck loading project:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.0 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_265)
[info] loading settings for project my-project-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /builds/my-project/project
[debug] not up to date. inChanged = true, force = false
[debug] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/builds/my-project/project/"), "my-project-build")...
```

I have the same problem launching any sbt command (version, compile, run, ...)

Waiting more thant 1 hour, the loading project step finish but after 24 hours the jobs is still not terminated
here is my build.sbt:

```
name := "batch_spark"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

logLevel := Level.Debug

val sparkVersion = "2.3.2"
val hbaseVersion = "1.1.7"
val clusterVersion = "4.7.0.2.6.5.0-292"

checksums in update := Nil
useCoursier := false

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",

  "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-core" % "4.7.0.2.6.5.102-5",
  "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-spark2" % clusterVersion,

  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % hbaseVersion ,
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % hbaseVersion,
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % hbaseVersion,
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % hbaseVersion,

  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.9.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.9.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.8",
  "org.apache.thrift" % "libfb303" % "0.9.2",
  "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.13.0"

)
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.8"
dependencyOverrides += "com.google.protobuf" % "protobuf-java" % "2.5.0"
resolvers += "Hortonworks repository" at "https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases"
resolvers += "conjars" at "https://conjars.org/repo/"
resolvers += "miroir-artifactory" at "https://artifactory-toto.fr/artifactory/"

mainClass in assembly := Some("fr.company.service.SparkPhoenix")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  // META-INF discarding
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: does it work on other machines? What is the output of sbt version? Can you share your `build.sbt`?

Comment: @TomerShetah Hi, I add the build.sbt . Waiting more thant 1 hour, the loading project step finish but after 24 hours the jobs is still not terminated